# How to auto add references of Dlls in new project

Tags: .net, dll, reference, project

I am using "thrid party controls dlls" in my own dll "MyControl.Dll", Now i want when i use "MyControl.dll" in other projects its will auto add reference of all dlls in a project ("MyControl.dll" and "thrid party controls dlls").

Please give me the way how can i do this.

Im using c# and vb.net VS2008.

Comment: You don't need a reference added for them, you simply need to have these DLLs copied.  Which VS does automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure Visual Studio can do this. However, you could try to roll your own project template so that the required dlls are already added to your project. This is only good for new projects though.

Visual Studio add reference dialog does have the "recent" list which shows assemblies which you have recently used. This provides a quick way to add all of the references you use on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure Visual Studio doesn't do this intentionally. You don't want to add references without the developer's knowledge - you can end up with conflicts or worse - a security hazard.

Comment: thanks for replay, i see that we can do but there is some registration or setting in your drive dll these things i want to know it...